# Organize sections automatically in different pages

Tags: javascript, html, pagination, format, structure

What I would like to get some help with dividing a website in pages, similar to how a forum is organized.

What I mean is that for example a thread has at most 10 posts and when you post an 11th, the oldest post will go to Page 2 and continue that way. Whats the best or easiest way to achieve this? Are there several ways of doing that with HTML alone, or html and Javascript, or PHP?

Comment: The best an easiest way: don't reinvent the wheel. Find some open-source library that already does this an tailor it for your needs.

Comment: Yeah I know, im just stubborn that way :)

Comment: I don't think this is the right place to find tutorials....

Comment: Perhaps not, but it is here for help. And I cant search a tutorial on an abstract concept without knowing even if there is a term for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of what you are describing is called pagination.

> [Pagination in web content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination)
>
> On the Internet, pagination is used for such things as displaying a
>   limited number of results on search engine results pages, or showing a
>   limited number of posts when viewing a forum thread. Pagination is
>   used in some form in almost every web application to divide returned
>   data and display it on multiple pages. Pagination also includes the
>   logic of preparing and displaying the links to the various pages.
>
> Pagination can be handled client-side or server-side. Server-side
>   pagination is more common. Client-side pagination can be used when
>   there are very few records to be accessed, in which case all records
>   can be returned, and the client can use JavaScript to view the
>   separate pages. By using AJAX, hybrid server/client-side pagination
>   can be used, in which Javascript is used to request the subsequent
>   page which is loaded and inserted into the Document Object Model via
>   AJAX.
>
> Server-side pagination is appropriate for large data sets providing
>   faster initial page load, accessibility for those not running
>   Javascript, and complex view business logic.
>
> Correctly implementing pagination can be difficult. There are many
>   different usability questions such as should "previous" and "next"
>   links be included, how many links to pages should be displayed, and
>   should there be a link to the first and last pages. Also ability to
>   define the number of records displayed in a single page is useful.

Also you can read this for [comparison of pagination algorithms](http://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-19853-3_56).

Comment: THank you, ill check it out. Fitting name, but still hard to imagine it. :P

Answer (score 0):

Paging is something you're going to want to do on the server with PHP before you get to HTML. The primary goal of paging is to conserve bandwidth. (You don't want to send 1000 records down to the browser if the user is going to stop reading after the first 10.) There are also performance and usability concerns.

The actual implementation varies wildly depending on your toolset, database technology, application framework, and personal preference.

If you're using MySQL, you'll want to look into `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`, which will allow you to select "pages" of data for a query. It may be as simple as adding a couple query string parameters to your URL and passing those on (being careful to clean them of any SQL injection attacks, of course) to your existing query.

I don't know if I can be more specific without having more details about the code you're working with.

Comment: No code right now, just a basic concept of the website, I just wanna have pictures with text, kinda like a blog, and so that i show about 10 pictures per page.

So does all the material have to be injected via Php? or would I have different php documents that would load in and sort themselfs?

I kinda expected an answer a bit like 

1. Do like this with this.
2. Then do this , because of that.... etc etc :)

or how do most learn this, I never came across an examaple or explanation in any of the books ive read on the subjects.

Comment: If your end goal is to learn, I'd recommend searching for a tutorial that will walk you through creating your first application. If your end goal is to have a website, I'd recommend looking into WordPress or a similar content management system.

Comment: And to more directly answer your question: The simplest solution to implement would be to use a set of HTML pages where you manage the content directly, but this would be very difficult to maintain. A more complex solution that would be easier to maintain would be to write a PHP application that stores content in a database and dynamically generates all of the HTML. There are near infinite possibilities in between. The actual file structure can vary as well. For HTML, it might be page1.html, page2.html, etc. For PHP, it might be page.php?p=1, page.php?p=2, etc.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to have like a slideshow with buttons, basicly a back and forward button on the sides, and a div inside in center witch some pictures and text, almost like a powerpoint presentation. But since i expect to put alot pictures and content, I dont want all to load at once. So something like load the first 10 would be desirable, and then when you are at slide 10, and you press forward next 10 is loaded, and those initial 10 are still there just slide away behind the div (overflow:hidden),  "left: -xpx"

Comment: You're going to want to read up on AJAX and JSON. JSON is a data format you can use to send down a page of data at a time. AJAX is how you can request the new data after your page has loaded.

Comment: I'll get on that as soon as I feel somewhat confident with php, I am a bit confused though, aren't you able to do same thing with PHP include()

Comment: PHP runs on the server before the page is sent down to the browser. You can certainly use PHP to build up the page with all of your content, but it can result in a heavy download depending on how much content you intend to have.